# Importing custom formatted excel data into R

Tags: r, excel, import, formatting

I'm trying to analyse some race data in R. The data is mainly finishing times, currently in the custom format hh:mm:ss, however when imported to R I cannot do any analysis as I'll always receive the following error message:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(Swim) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Can anyone advice how best to get around this, albeit probably simple, stumbling block for me? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us the code you are using and some toy data to go with it.

Comment: Whats the format of `swim` after you import to R .. maybe this can help http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tutorial-on-reading-and-importing-excel-files-into-r/

Answer (score 0):

When you are importing a column with the format hh:mm:ss from excel to r it will be imported as factor (or character, depending on the import function/settings). That is the reason for your error message (character/factor is neither numerical or logical).

To be able to do any analysis on the data, you need to do some conversion. You have your data as character you can do

```
as.integer(as.POSIXct(Swim, format="%H:%M:%S")) %% 86400
```

to get the hh:mm:ss as number of seconds. If Swim is a factor you can do:

```
Swim <- as.character(Swim)
```

to get it as a character.